# Solving recursive formula dependent on a periodic function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, periodic-functions

Say we have some initial values $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$ and a recursive formula $a_n = f(n) + c_{1}a_{n-1} + c_{2}a_{n-2} + \dots + c_{k}a_{n-k}$ Where $f(n)$ is periodic and $a_n,f(n),c_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

For example let $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n = f(n) + 2a_{n-1}$ where $f(n) = 1,2,1,2 \dots$

How can we generally solve this kind of formula?

I was initially thinking to solve the linear recurrence relation for each value of $f(n)$ and then merge the subsequences, but not sure how this should be done. The main issue is how to describe the extra shifting done each time we get a higher value for $f(n)$

In the example we can solve $a_{n,1} = 1 + 2a_{n-1,1}$ and get $a_{n,1} = 2^n - 1$

And solve $a_{n,2} = 2 + 2a_{n-1,2}$ and get $a_{n,2} = 3\cdot2^{n-1} - 2$

Though I am not sure how to merge them to get $a_n$ which first values are $a_n= 1, 3, 8, 17, 36,..$ given by multiplying by $2$ and adding $1$ or $2$ alternately.

Comment: Your particular example seems to have the generating function $\frac{x(1+x+x^2)}{(1-x)(1+x)(1-2x)}$ and closed form $a_n=\frac16(7\times2^n -(-1)^n-9)$ for $n\ge 1$, if I have not made an arithmetic error.  My guess is that for more complicated examples, a generating function might be possible with some effort while a closed form would be a mess.  Personally I would just use the recurrence.

Comment: The solution to

$$
a_n = b a_{n-1}+ f_n, \ a_0= a^0
$$

is given by

$$
a_n=b^{n-1} \left(\sum _{k= 0}^{n-1} b^{-(k+1)} f_{k}+b (a^0-f_0)\right)
$$

now posing 

$$
f_n = \frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^{n+1}+3\right), b = 2, a_1 = 1
$$

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{6} \left((-1)^{n+1}+7\ 2^n-9\right)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\,f(n)\,$ has period $\,K\,$, then eliminating $\,f(n+K)=f(n)\,$ between the two recurrence relations for $\,a_n+K\,$ and $\,a_n\,$ gives a linear homogeneous recurrence that no longer includes $\,f(n)\,$, which can be solved with the usual methods.

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a_{n+K} &= f(n+K) + c_{1}a_{n+K-1} + c_{2}a_{n+K-2} + \dots + c_{k}a_{n+K-k}
\\ a_n &= f(n) + c_{1}a_{n-1} + c_{2}a_{n-2} + \dots + c_{k}a_{n-k}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\implies\quad\quad a_{n+K} = a_n &+ (c_{1}a_{n+K-1} + c_{2}a_{n+K-2} + \dots + c_{k}a_{n+K-k}) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
\\ &- (c_{1}a_{n-1} + c_{2}a_{n-2} + \dots + c_{k}a_{n-k})
\end{align}
$$

It can be shown that if the characteristic polynomial of the original recurrence is $\,p(t)\,$ then the characteristic polynomial of the derived recurrence is $\,(t^K-1)\,p(t)\,$.

> For example let $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n = f(n) + 2a_{n-1}$ where $f(n) = 1,2,1,2 \dots$

This is the case $\,k=1\,$, $\,p(t)=t-2\,$, $\,K=2\,$.

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a_{n+2} &= f(n+2) + 2a_{n+1}
\\ a_n &= f(n) + 2a_{n-1}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\implies\quad\quad a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} + a_n  - 2a_{n-1} \quad\quad\;\;
$$

The characteristic polynomial is $\,t^3-2t^2-t+2 = (t^2-1)(t-2)\,$, with roots $\,\pm 1, 2\,$, so $\,a_n = C_1 + C_2 \,(-1)^n + C_3 \,2^n\,$ where $\,C_1,C_2,C_3\,$ are determined from the initial conditions.